# SharePoint 2010 Global Drop-down Top Level Sites

Tags: sharepoint, drop-down-menu, sharepoint-2010

On SharePoint 2010 I'm trying to create a drop-down menu in my global navigation for top-level sites. I know how to do a drop-down of subsites under a site but I want a drop-down for sites made at the root of the site collection. The title for the site drop-down would not be a hyperlink whereas normal subsite drop-down titles are. Here's a visual of what I'm trying to do:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2y2El6MOQlAUjJWYTJ4bVEzQjQ/view?usp=sharing_eid